# regex with all keyboard characters

Tags: php, regex

I need regex with all english keyboard characters that works from all situations. Right now, I'm using this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*)\]\[(+=._-].*/
```

But the text like this don't work:

> "I'm good!", told Billy!

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match("#^[a-z0-9\r\n\t " . preg_quote('`~!@#$%^&*()_+{}[]:";\'<>?,./'). "].*#i", $string, $matches)
```

u can remove `\r\n\t` if u dont need TAB and ENTER

Answer (score 1):

Space is missing.

The `.*` at the end is not what you wanted.

Instead, end with `*` to repeat the character set; then have a `$` to 'anchor' the regexp at the end of the string.

```
/^[ -~]*$/
```

might work correctly -- it includes space and all visible characters.  See an ascii chart to verify.  Or you may need to add `\t` for tab and something for `Return`.